# javafx graphics context will not render image

Tags: javafx

I have the file rhino.gif in the same directory as this program.
It compiles just fine but the image will not render onto the screen.
Note that the image knows its dimensions (300X300).

What am I missing?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ImageShower extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        //runs before GUI starts
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primary)
    {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Canvas c = new Canvas(500,500);
        GraphicsContext pen =  c.getGraphicsContext2D();
        Image im = null;
        ImageView iv = new ImageView();
            //im = new Image(new FileInputStream(new File("rhino.gif")));
            im = new Image("file:/Users/morrison/teaching/java/rhino.gif");
            System.out.println(im);
            pen.drawImage(im, 100, 100, 300, 300);
            System.out.println(im.getWidth());
            System.out.println(im.getHeight());
        primary.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primary.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void stop()
    {
        //run after GUI ends.
        //prevent data loss.
        //clean up any messes.
        System.out.println("Gahhhhh ! My last gasp prior to death!");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, even with an animated GIF file (though it only draws the first frame). Have you tried other GIF files? Maybe there's something about `rhino.gif` that's causing the problem.

Comment: https://faculty.ncssm.edu/~morrison/rhino.gif  Download it and see if it displays.  I'd be interested in your result.

Comment: The image is displayed in the `Canvas` for me. What version of JavaFX are you using? I'm using JavaFX 13.0.2. Maybe there was a bug that is fixed (purposely or otherwise) in newer versions. I'm also on Windows 10, if that matters at all.